# Binding jquery post data to c# type

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

My action method takes a custom C# class - **Comment.cs :**

```
public class Comment
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public int CardID {get; set;}
  public int UserID {get;set;}
  public string Comment {get;set;}
}
```

In my view I have a form with input fields for each property in the class except for ID (it's generated by the database).  I prevent the default behavior on form submission with jquery and use $.post like this -

```
$('.form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var comment = this.Comment.value;
  var cardId = this.CardID.value;
  var userId = this.UserID.value;
  $.post('/Cards/AddComment',
      {
        Comment: comment,
        CardID: cardId,
        UserID: userId
      });
});
```

Html -

```
<form asp-controller="Cards" asp-action="AddComment" id="comment-form">
    <input class="form-control" name="Comment" placeholder="Leave a comment.." />
    <input class="form-control" name="CardID" type="hidden" />
    <input class="form-control" name="UserID" value="@User.Claims.ElementAt(0).Value" type="hidden" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

action method -

```
public IActionResult AddComment(Comment comment)
{
  // comment.Comment == null
  // comment.CardID == null
  // comment.UserID == null
}
```

I'm trying to automagically cast my posted jQuery data to a Comment type but it isn't working.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You described how to do it :) So what it is the problem?

Comment: It isn't working?  I've debugged and the properties of the Comment are null.  They aren't bound to the object.

Comment: Everything looks correct except of `Comment.Comment` property. You will get a compile error related to property name. Also post your html

Comment: Nah that property isn't going to cause a compile error.  it's comment.Comment.  lowercase.Uppercase

Comment: @Albert  You say everything looks correct?  Like is that how model binding works, it's that simple?

Comment: yes. Just tried it and default model binder works. Two things I changed: 1) Renamed class `Comment` to `CommentModel` to escape the compile error. 2) Set `value` attributes for all three inputs in markup directly.